# replacement for useThousandsSeparator in flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, numberformatter

I've been migrating to flex 4.5 from flex 4.

I've used Numberformatter  to format number in the following method:

```
var numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
numberFormatter.precision=1;
numberFormatter.useThousandsSeparator=true;
```

that would work for an `mx` component. but if i'd like to use `s` component, both
of these properties don't apply.

I've learned that I can use `fractionalDigits` instead of `percision`.

I still didn't find a way to replace the propery `useThousandsSeparator`. that actually adds "`,`" as a thousand seperator.

any ideas how to reslve the issue?

thank you

Kfir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thousand separator has be replaced by groupingSeparator

Comment: can you provide an example? groupingSeparator sets what the seperator will be. how do I enable it ?

Comment: ah ok i found it! numberFormatter.groupingPattern="3;*" awesome thanks